# Create articles via the Joomla API

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to create a significant number of very similar articles in Joomla 3.x, and I'm looking for a way to do that by scripting.

I'm very new to Joomla (and web stuff in general), but I thought it shouldn't be too hard to figure out the Joomla API. Alas, after spending hours of trial and error and googling, I'm not even near getting a simple demonstration to run. The API documentation is not very helpful and the few examples I found online are mostly for Joomla 1.x and don't work anymore.

Can anyone provide me a simple hello-world style example that creates a dummy article? I would prefer the CLI interface, but the web interface would also be ok.

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, I missed that somehow. And actually, there I found the [answer to my question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5361/15332). Thanks for the pointer!